# Will Ubuntu QML apps be cross-platform?

Tags: application-development, qml, ubuntu-sdk, crossplatform

I am creating a voice-chat app for Ubuntu using the Ubuntu SDK; will it work on windows and mac in the future?

If not, I will be switching from using the SDK to plain Qt or GTK.

Answer (score 4):

While in theory the Ubuntu SDK should be cross-platform, the main focus has been to develop and polish it for Ubuntu first, so no work has been done to package it for other platforms.

However, this is a desirable goal, and we could use all the help we can get!

Comment: Where could I help with this then?